# How to put div with menu next to the image

Tags: html, css

Okay, since what I've added was a mess, hopefully this time I did better job.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKqpow

```
#myTopnav{
clear:right;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Can't do that because then my menu gets messy

This snippet shows what the current page look like but what I want to achieve is [this(click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQLbp.png) - basically I want to have menu at the bottom of header like shown on the image.

Comment: It's very unclear what you actually want.  Can you please edit the question and clarify what the *desired layout* is?

Comment: @cale_b doesn't image show enough what I want?

Comment: Nope.  Completely unclear.    What is "right here"?  You have no element with content "right here", so what should go there?

Comment: @cale_b will add everything now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of maintaining as much of the code you have and trying to account for responsive changes, this is what I would do:

1. Wrap the `#myTopnav` and `.social` elements in another `div`, give a class that makes sense. Here I've called it `.nav-group`.
2. Give `.icon` a display value of `inline-block`, and set a relative width (20% is approximate to what you have here)
3. Do the same for the new div (`.nav-group` in this case, with a width of 80%). Set its position to `relative`.
4. Set `.social` and `#myTopnav` position to `absolute`, and align accordingly.

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaPZgW

This solution assumes you want the height of the header to scale proportionally as the screen size changes, preserving the dimensions of the logo/icon/image on the left.

However, you are going to run into some issues with this design on smaller screens - you will see what I mean once you get to the breakpoint in your CSS. There are a lot of different ways to address the issue, depending on what you want to happen at that width and smaller.

Comment: I gotta edit everything, I have to give you guys all the code

Comment: @cale_b - There are no floats being applied to inline-block elements in my snippet, so I'm not sure why the comment. As for using classes, I've edited the answer to unpack the idea a little more. As avoiding id's is generally accepted practice in CSS, I didn't think it needed exposition.

Comment: @TimmyTurner - yeah, please. As much as you reasonably can. I should have asked for more detail in the first place.

Comment: thank for that. I've question though, can't I get 100% width of navigation bar? Right now it's on 80%~ on my resolution

Comment: @TimmyTurner - the navigation bar should be 100% with width of the new container, which itself has a width of 80% ('.nav-group' in my pen). The only way it would be 80% is if that width is specifically applied to the bar itself. It is working as expected in my pen, so perhaps review your code against mine to make sure you're adding the new container and applying the styles correctly.

Comment: you're right, it works in your pen but if the screen resolution is greater then the width is not 100% :/

Comment: I see - ok, I've updated the answer with a corrected pen. Added `display: table;` to `.header`, and changed max-width on the `.icon img` to just `width`. That should do it.